# Force apt(8) to generate color through pipe?

Tags: apt, pipe, colors

Output from `apt list`is often tens of thousands line long, so I usually run instead

```
apt list | less # or another program
```

but there's no color in this way. Can I retain the color while piping `apt(8)`'s output?

- This one has already failed:

  ```
  sudo apt install expect
  unbuffer apt list | less
  ```

  `unbuffer` converts all invisible characters to visible counterparts.
- From `man apt`, I also tried this:

  ```
  apt -o APT:Color=true list | less
  ```

  `apt` says "Configuration item specification must have an =<var>" but I don't know the correct value for <val>.

Comment: The expected option is `-o APT::Color=true`. However, [when `apt` determines that the file descriptor does not refer to a terminal, e.g., the pipe, it sets `APT::Color` to `"false"`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/766b24b7f7484751950c76bc66d3d6cdeaf949a5/apt-private/private-output.cc#L91), overriding the supplied option.

Comment: When a program is started using [`unbuffer`](https://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pty/unbuffer.c.html), its output is redirected to a pseudoterminal, and is consequently line-buffered. Since the output file descriptor is a terminal and [`APT::Color` is set to `true` by default for `apt`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/766b24b7f7484751950c76bc66d3d6cdeaf949a5/apt-private/private-cmndline.cc#L466), color is enabled. That's how `unbuffer` is able to pass colored output to the pipe.

Comment: [`ptyFork`](https://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pty/pty_fork.c.html#ptyFork) implements the pseudoterminal functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found the fault.

Actually the control character conversion is not done by `unbuffer(1)`, but **`less(1)`** itself. So the answer is simple: stick to `unbuffer` and give an option to `less` to tell it to stop converting Escapes.

```
unbuffer apt list | less -R
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/117841/get-colors-in-less-or-more